# Weird quick switching between normal and hover state CSS

Tags: html, css

I just created a custom styled button with an effect when hovering. However if you are unlucky and find a specific spot while hovering on the button it quickly switches between the normal and hover state.

[image: Custom button glitching between states]

My code:

```css
button {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background .2s, transform .2s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 0 blue;
  transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
}

button:active {
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<button>I am a button</button>
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/rmu91qLh/1/)

Is there a trick to solve this issue?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I can't reproduce it in a webkit browser.

Comment: Brave Version 1.8.96 Chromium: 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

The cause is the transform on hover. As soon as you stop hovering, the button goes back to place. If you've only moved one pixel away, you are now hovering the button again, which moves 1px away, and now is not hovered, and so on.

The best solution would be to remove the transform effect.

If you can't, a simple solution would be to add a transparent border around the button when it's hovered. You'll have to go another pixel to stop hovering the button, and when the hover stops you'll be outside of the new button position.

```css
button {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background .2s, transform .2s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 0 blue;
  transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

button:active {
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<button>I am a button</button>
```

Comment: I don't know, this seems worse UI than the original issue. I mean, I should say, I think this is the correct issue, but maybe not the best solution.

Comment: I agree. My solution is mainly technical. The person responsible for the UI/UX...

Comment: This is a good idea! However I think instead of a border you should use an outline (`outline: 5px solid transparent;`) as a border would be inside the moving button not on the outside.
But as I am using a border radius the glitch effect still is going to happen at the edges. For people out there using a button without a border-radius this is great!

Comment: Since you're moving it one 1px, even with border radius, a border of 1px is enough to compensate. It addition, the outline is not hoverable, so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to add a container with a small padding, and check the hover on it instead of the button. Since it doesn't move, you shouldn't have the problem.

```css
#buttonContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

button {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background .2s, transform .2s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonContainer:hover button{
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 0 blue;
  transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
}

button:active {
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
    <button>I am a button</button>
</div>
```